# How to trigger an event when google maps searchBox updated result list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find out if the height of the `.pac-container` changed (*see green border in figure*). I tried to trigger the event by a keypress of the input field.

```js
$('#pac-input').on('keypress', function() {
    var height = $('.pac-container').outerHeight();
});
```

But the update of the result list follows a few milliseconds later so the update comes to late. Therefore I want to trigger my function when the result list changed.

[image: searchBox classes]

**Is there any event I can check when the result list is updated?**

- [Working example here...](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

---

#### Update

Meanwhile my solution is to set several `setTimeout()` events, which is not really elegant but it works with a some little delay.

```js
$('#pac-input').on('focus keypress', function() {        
        checkPacHeight();
        setTimeout(checkPacHeight, 500);
        setTimeout(checkPacHeight, 1000);
    });

function checkPacHeight(){
    var count = $(".pac-container .pac-item").length;
    var height = $('.pac-container').outerHeight();
    console.log(count+' results and height is: '+height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation page you linked, there is an event fired when the places are changed.

```
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    doSomeThings();
}
```

Checking the height of the element is thinking outside the box, but the best solution would be an event listener for this situation.

Comment: yes, but that event gets fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve more details for that place and not when he just input a new letter... It's used in the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) I linked...